# How to set TextBox Comment Value Input as Table Data Insert on MS Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a main "final table" being updated through VBA based on many inputs of a Form and other tables data. I am trying to callout a TextBox object value that exists in a form to the VBA code so user can add a comment to all the data being inserted into the final table.

```
Dim strComment As String
strComment = TextBox_Comment.Value

strSQL = "INSERT INTO Main_Table (Period, Monthp, Order, Comment)"
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT ""Weekly"" AS Period, [001_SelectedMonth].Monthp, [001_OrderTable].Order, strComment AS Comment FROM 001_SelectedMonth, 001_OrderTable;"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

The code works fine when I remove both the "Comment" from the Main Table insertion points and the "strComment AS Comment" part of the code. Otherwise I get the Run-Time Error '3061', Too few parameters. Expected 1.

**Question**: is there a way for me to callout the text box value to be inserted in the database as a field data for all the data being added or should I use another method to do this?

Example of the final table:

[image: Final Table]

Comment: Is `strComment` the name of a control on a form?  If so, it cannot be referenced in a SQL string like that.  I suggest creating a temporary QueryDef, adding a parameter for that column, then assigning the form control value to that QueryDef parameter.

Comment: The word "order" is also an SQL reserved word, as in "ORDER BY", and may need to be delimited liked '[Order]'.

Comment: And do you really want two source tables added without a join?  The current code will produce a Cartesian product of all the rows in the two tables `001_SelectedMonth` and `001_OrderTable`.

Comment: @CPerkins the "Order" is just an example, I avoided using the terms I'm currently using in the code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space and proper concatenation:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Main_Table ([Period], Monthp, [Order], [Comment]) "
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT 'Weekly' AS [Period], [001_SelectedMonth].Monthp, [001_OrderTable].Order, '" & strComment & "' AS [Comment] FROM 001_SelectedMonth, 001_OrderTable;"
```

That said, use parameters to avoid the concatenation.

Comment: This goes against common advice to avoid SQL injection.  I'm not as fussy as some--especially within in Access which is already inherently insecure--but I've been "slapped in the face" numerous times on SO for suggesting this type of code.

Comment: @Gustav, this actually solved my issue. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @CPerkins: True. Tired of being bashed for a direct answer to a question, I usually include the disclaimer that parameters should be preferred. I use parameters nearly throughout myself, but sometimes concatenating is both convenient and totally safe. It may not be the case here, but we don't know what level of validation `TextBox_Comment`has passed.

Comment: @Gustav  I'm not trying to bash your answers, hence my attempt to simply "pass on the message" that I got so often a few years ago.  I'm surprised that I'm the only one who piped up.  At least back then, it was just part of the culture to encourage safe programming habits, boldly and directly.  I also remember when more users actually attempted to hold to the standard of encouraging high quality answers with the questions.  It seems more and more (at least with Access) that answers are just quick-fix solutions to poorly researched questions.

Comment: @CPerkins: I agree. Often, like here, there is a direct answer to "why does my code fail". I can write that answer in seconds, while a lengthy and educating alternative answer and explanation may take much longer time - which I often don't have available as real work has priority. Of course, when I retire, the picture may change ...